# Determining the Referer using PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have a bunch of HTML pages with a form on each page for users to subscribe to a newsletter. This form submits to subscribe.php here i want to determine the page the user came from and redirect it to the same page.

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']);
```

is giving me an error

[image]

Comment: might be an .htaccess issue. Can you show us the htaccess file ?

Comment: not all browsers send a referer, and of those that do, some send fake ones. You cannot use the referer data as you are and expect things to work reliably, even after you fix the typo in your code.

Comment: Isn't it `HTTP_REFERER`? (The misspelling is unfortunately set in stone in the spec.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spelling mistake, the associated name is `HTTP_REFERER`.

This generates a redirect to '', which is the same page and hence looping forever and causing the error.

Answer (score 3):

Try validating that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']` is not pointing to the url which has this code, in which case do something else other than creating an infinite loop.

It also should be `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` with one R, you may want to test your code in a strict environment which actually gives you an error because your code is probably throwing an undefined index notice, and then returning null which is cast as an empty string to the location, which redirects to itself.

Comment: Or go the simple way- include the originating page in your subscribe request and use that.